# Next.js 404 on refresh

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have Next.js  page like `page.js` so it can be reach through `http://localhost:3000/page`. But for some reason I would like to get this page through an another url  `http://localhost:3000/my-page`

So I used Link component like this way

```js
<link href="/page" as="my-page">
    <a>
        My link to page
    </a>
</link>
```

Problem is that if I refresh browser, I get a 404 error page if I do not use `as` property it works.

How can I prevent this behavior ?

Comment: That isn't what `as` is for. See [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes). Don't do that. It breaks (as you've discovered).

Comment: May do you know a way to achieve what I would ?

Comment: Honestly: Stop wanting that. Give the page the URL you want it to have. Don't have multiple URLs going to the same place. Don't try to load one URL while telling the user it is a different URL.

Comment: Is it bad pratice ? what if I have one page with multiple section (so differents url) in it ?

Comment: If it has multiple sections then you use `#id_of_element` to link to the section. If it has different paths, then you don't have **one** page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using a SPA, in this cases the router is different because the routes are loaded with the principal component

Comment: How can the OP prevent this behavior?

Comment: May do you know a way to achieve what I would ?